# Cannot render partial view within partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this view:

```
<div>
    ...
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial/_Arena); }
</div>
```

This is the arena partial view:

```
<div>
    ...
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Arena/_PlayerSection"); }
</div>
```

But `_Arena.cshtml` is throwing an error when rendering `_PlayerSection.cshtml`.  Here is the file structure:

```
Partial ->
    _Arena.cshtml
    Arena ->
        _PlayerSection.cshtml
```

I have tried using `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_PlayerSection"); }` with `_PlayerSection.cshtml` in the same directory but there is still an error finding the file.  I would like the partial views to be in this subdirectory for organizational purposes instead of lumping them all in the /Views/Shared directory.

Comment: Did yo build the project ?or did you create a controller?

Comment: I'm confused about the question, the project builds just fine, the problem is a runtime exception when I hit an action that returns this view.

Comment: Post the error you are getting. Also, try changing your partial code blocks to @Html.Partial("Arena/_PlayerSection")

Comment: I will post the full error later today, but it's a simple file not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the root directory for partial relative paths are not determined by the location of the file, but by the location of the view directory.

So, in my case, with a structure like this:

```
ServerRoot ->
    Views ->
        Arena ->
            BaseView.cshtml
            Partial ->
                _Arena.cshtml
                ArenaPartial ->
                    _PlayerSection.cshtml
```

I had to use `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial/ArenaPartial/_PlayerSection"); }` in order for it to work.